# Java for loop to create n amount of object

Tags: java, arraylist

I need some help. I want to create a for loop that creates n number of objects of a class, and then adds them into an arraylist. Something like this:

```
//Player is a custom class 
ArrayList<Player> numberofPlayersArray;
numberofPlayersArray = new ArrayList<Player>();

//n is a variable for the number of Player class objects that I want to create
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {

    //this is what I can come up with but I am missing something 

     Player p;
     p = new Player
     numberofPlayersArray.add(p);

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are thinking correct. What's the problem? Is that the source code you're trying to compile? In that case, add () after new Player. Like this:  Player p = new Player();   numberOfPlayers.add(p);   (assuming your Player class has a default constructor.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: problem is p must be null because I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I call p.method();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Player is a custom class 
ArrayList<Player> numberofPlayersArray = new ArrayList<Player>(n);

//n is a variable for the number of Player class objects that I want to create
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

     Player p = new Player();
     numberofPlayersArray.add(p);
}
```

Note that it's better to initialize the `ArrayList` with the size, if it is known (as in your case)

Comment: OK now how would I call p.method(); ie: p.dosomething();

Comment: what do you mean 'how would I call'? Just call it as you wrote.

Comment: problem is p must be null because I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I call p.method();

Comment: ask another question including the entire source code and point where the null pointer exception happens.

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks syntactically correct with one exception.

Change

```
p = new Player
```

to

```
p = new Player();
```

I'm assuming the variable `n` is declared and initialized and the `Player` class is defined with an argless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here, just do

```
p = new Player();
```

(but this might just have been a typo) and the playerlist will be populated with n different Player objects.

Note, that I'm just assuming, you want to use the default constructor for Player.

Naming hint: you shouldn't name a List '..Array', unless you want to confuse yourself ;) Just name it '..List'

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to code to the interface (rather than the concrete class).

```
List<Player> numberofPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>(n);
```

Forgetting to do this (or not knowing about it) is a common beginners mistake.

If you decide to switch to an alternative list implementation later on (LinkedList or maybe a Google Collection or an Apache Commons Collection list) you won't have to change every reference to the list - just the initial allocation.